# Numbers not populating in Calculator window

Tags: javascript, project, calculator, addeventlistener, queryselector

I am working on building a calculator and at the moment I am stuck on a specific issue.  I can't get the numbers to populate in the calculator window when clicked.

I have had a difficult time understanding query selectors and event listeners, so I'm assuming I am making a mistake somewhere in my Javascript.

I have created a query selector that targets the .window-content class.  The windowValue variable starts off as blank.  I then have a query selector for the container that houses the calculator with an Event Listener awaiting a click.

Code in question is below:

```
const screen = document.querySelector(".window-content");
let windowValue = ""; 
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName !== "button") return;

  let buttonText = tgt.innerText; 
  if (buttonText == 'X') { 
    buttonText = '*';
    windowValue += buttonText;
    screen.value = windowValue;
  } else if (buttonText == 'CA') { 
    windowValue = "";
    screen.value = windowValue;
  } else if (buttonText == '') { 
    windowValue = windowValue.slice(0,-1);
    screen.value = windowValue;
  } else if (buttonText == '=') { 
    screen.value = operate(firstNum, secondNum, operator);
    windowValue = screen.value;
    firstNum = "";
    operator = "";
    secondNum = "";
  } else if (buttonText.match(/[0-9]/)) { 
    windowValue += buttonText; 
    screen.value = windowValue;
  } else { 
    firstNum = windowValue;
    operator = buttonText;
    windowValue = "";
    windowValue += buttonText;
  windowContent.innerText = windowValue;
  }
})
```

Comment: HTML doesn't have a built-in `btn` element. Did you actually use a `<btn>` instead of `<button>` or it's just a typo?

Comment: @InSync Whoops, yes that was a mistake on my end. Just updated it, but problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mistake is you use `querySelector`, with this you can only apply `addEventListener` only on first element instead of all element with class `.container`. Just replace that to `querySelectorAll` and make a looping to apply `click` event to all `button`.

```js
const screen = document.querySelector(".window-content");
let windowValue = ""; 
[...document.querySelectorAll(".container")].forEach(function (container) {
  container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    console.log(tgt);
    //if (tgt.tagName !== "button") return;

    let buttonText = tgt.innerText; 
    console.log(buttonText);
    if (buttonText == 'X') { 
      buttonText = '*';
      windowValue += buttonText;
      screen.value = windowValue;
    } else if (buttonText == 'CA') { 
      windowValue = "";
      screen.value = windowValue;
    } else if (buttonText == '') { 
      windowValue = windowValue.slice(0,-1);
      screen.value = windowValue;
    } else if (buttonText == '=') { 
      screen.value = operate(firstNum, secondNum, operator);
      windowValue = screen.value;
      firstNum = "";
      operator = "";
      secondNum = "";
    } else if (buttonText.match(/[0-9]/)) { 
      windowValue += buttonText; 
      screen.value = windowValue;
    } else { 
      firstNum = windowValue;
      operator = buttonText;
      windowValue = "";
      windowValue += buttonText;
      windowContent.innerText = windowValue;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <button class="container">X</button>
  <button class="container">CA</button>
  <button class="container"></button>
  <button class="container">=</button>
  <button class="container">1</button>
  <button class="container">2</button>
  <button class="container">3</button>
  <button class="container">4</button>
  <button class="container">5</button>
  <button class="container">6</button>
  <button class="container">7</button>
  <button class="container">8</button>
  <button class="container">9</button>
  <button class="container">0</button>
</div>
<br />
<textarea class="window-content"></textarea>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your help here.  Your explanation made perfect sense.